# Getting back into aerobic shape

Tags: cardio

I had a good year-plus daily biking habit (the commute). Since leaving the last company two months ago, I've been doing little more than sitting on my ass. I've a ski trip planned for a couple weeks from now. I'd prefer not to end up wheezing and in pain after the first run.

How long should it take me to get back into aerobic shape?

I'm 45, male, 19 stone.

Comment: You don't mention whether you were active during the two months. Did you just sit and nothing more?

Comment: Yes, no activity.  Hence "little more."

Comment: The general rule of thumb I've found is that to get back to point A, after a layoff of B, is A = Bx2. Took you probably 2-3 weeks to lose your training, so probably 10ish weeks to get back to where you were.

Comment: Cardio is only one part in getting in shape for skiing.  Are you also going to work on flexibility, hip/leg and trunk muscle strength?

Comment: I ski a bunch, and - unless I'm skiing bumps or other advanced stuff - I find that I'm much more likely to be strength limited in my legs than cardio limited.